# ¿Puedo volver a una rama antigua de mi proyecto y recuperarlo?

Tags: git

Me explico, tengo un proyecto con bastantes ramas anteriores y quiero volver a una en específico para recuperar cierto código útil que una vez estuvo ahí, lo que más me interesa es clonar el proyecto a como lo tenía en su día, no sólo los commits que realicé en su momento y no sé si es posible con un git reverse o con algún otro comando ¿Alguien me puede ayudar? ¡Gracias!

Comment: Puedes poner cualquier rama en cualquier commit. Las ramas son solo apuntadores a commits así que si quieres colocar una rama en un commit puedes hacerlo con `git branch -f una-rama un-commit`.

Comment: Muchas gracias @eftshift0 !!!

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer un

```
git checkout -b nombreRama
```

Y cambias a dicha rama, cuando revises el código que querías, recuerda volver a la rama anterior

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias Jose! Me ha servido de mucho.